# Is there a way to get what version of git is used for a repository?

Tags: git

As the title says.

Also, is it also possible to see what git version is used for commits?

My purpose is to see what git version is used for a repository, and see if I need to update my git to match.

Comment: Git's design is such that the *repository format* is independent of the *Git version*. Given an existing clone, simply inspect the `core.repositoryformatversion` number. As it happens all current Git versions handle all current repository format numbers (which are just 0 and 2; number 1 was intended to be used, but there was a goof along the way).

Comment: Thanks, that's the answer I'm looking for. So, there's no way to know if a repository has commits using, let say Git v2.31 ?

Comment: Correct. If repositories were strongly tied to specific Git versions, that would be a big hassle.

Answer (score -1):

Git has no concept of versions. But if you want to know the latest commit, then use this.
You can use the more common

```
              git log -1
```

or the less used

```
              git rev-parse HEAD
```

If you have not pushed yes, you can check the version of origin/master, or of FETCH_HEAD (see FETCH_HEAD)

```
          cd /path/to/your/local/cloned/repo
          git rev-parse origin/master
          git rev-parse FETCH_HEAD
```

That will give you the commit ID (SHA1) of what was last fetched.

I hope this solve your purpose, if not tell me, we have more solutions for this!!

Comment: I meant, the version of git itself, not the version of the repository. I want to know what git was used for a specific repository.

Comment: If you're using the command-line tools, running git --version should give you the version number.   git help and man git both hint at the available arguments you can pass to the command-line tool.

Comment: Yes, that one I know. What I mean is, 'get the git version used in a repository'. Not the git I have installed.